# epoll_wait event.data.fd is always 0

Tags: c, epoll

I'm trying to setup a basic server with epoll to handle multiple clients. However, the value of the variable `socket` (line 20) is equal to `0` on the first iteration, but it should be `3` (the `accept` socket).

The event is well registered, but with a socket value of `0`. I tried with different flags (`EPOLLIN`, `EPOLLOUT`), but nothing changes.

Here is the main function:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
        errx(1, "Usage: ./basic_server SERVER_IP SERVER_PORT");
    int cnx = prepare_socket(argv[1], argv[2]);

    int epoll_instance = epoll_create1(0);
    struct epoll_event event = {};
    event.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLIN;
    struct connection_t *queue = NULL;
    if (epoll_ctl(epoll_instance, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, cnx, &event) == -1)
        errx(1, "Failed to register server");
    while (1)
    {
        struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENTS];
        int events_count = epoll_wait(epoll_instance, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
        for (int event_idx = 0; event_idx < events_count; event_idx++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", events[event_idx].data.fd);
            int socket = events[event_idx].data.fd;  // line 20
            if (socket == cnx)
                queue = accept_client(epoll_instance, socket, queue);
            else
                communicate(socket, queue);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.data` field of `struct epoll_event` is not touched by the operating system, it is merely associated with the `fd` you add to your epoll instance and then returned *as is* when an event occurs. If you want `event.data.fd` to be the right file descriptor then you'll have to set it before calling `epoll_ctl`:

```c
struct epoll_event event = {};
event.data.fd = cnx; // <-- here
event.events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLIN;

// ...

int events_count = epoll_wait(epoll_instance, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);

// Now events[event_idx].data.fd == cnx as it should.
```

Comment: Or set it in the initializer: `struct epoll_event event = { .data = { .fd = cnx }, .events = EPOLLOUT | EPOLLIN };`.  Additionally, the original empty initializer is non-standard. At least one member initializer must appear within.  The standard idiom for all-default initialization is `= {0}`.